# How can I find the integers from a line of HTML using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The line:

```html
<span class="current">7</span>
```

Script that prints this output:

```py
current = actual_items.find("span", class_="current")
print(current)
```

My attempt:

```py
print(current.find("text", text=current.isdigit()))
```

**Expected output:**

```py
7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `text` attribute, e.g.:

```
current.text.strip()
```

Calling `strip` might not be necessary when working with a well formatted HTML, but from my experience, it's often needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) as `text=` parameter:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<span class="current">THIS IS NOT A NUMBER</span>
<span class="current">7</span>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print( soup.find('span', class_="current", text=str.isdigit).text )
```

Prints:

```
7
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the text inside of the div:

```
print(current.text)
```

This will tell you if it is a digit or not.

```
print(current.text.isdigit())
```